# Best statistical model for pre post measurement (RCT) with two groups (treatment and control) and baseline differences?

Tags: mixed-model

I know there are several different models to chose from. I would like to know which one is the most appropriate (advanced) and if I should include baseline differences concerning the dependent variable (which happened despite of randomization unfortunately). So far, I see three options:

Linear regression with group x time (2x2) interaction.
Mixed effects model with random intercept (because of the dependencies of the time variable?)
Post DV as criterium and group and pre measurement as predictors (not my preferable choice).

For the first two options, is it feasible to include the baseline on top as another predictor or does that interfere with the time variable in the interaction?

Thank you for your help!